# tang / clevis: automatic unlocking for luks device not triggered unless defined as _netdev

Tags: systemd, encryption, disk, luks, disk-encryption

I've setup a server with luks devices (not used for root partition), they are listed in `/etc/crypttab` this way

```
# <target name> <source device>      <key file>   <options>
luks_device_1  /dev/mapper/vg-lv_1   none         luks
...
```

I've also setup a `tang` server and bound the devices to tang using the command

```
clevis luks bind -d /dev/mapper/vg-lv_1 tang '{"url":"http://svr"}'
```

finally I enable the units `clevis-luks-askpass.path` and `clevis-luks-askpass.service` to have the automatic unlocking mechanism working at boot.

However the devices are not unlocked at boot, the password is asked on the console, **unless** I add in the file `/etc/crypttab` the string `_netdev` in the `options` section. But I'm not really fond of that because `_netdev` is supposed to be used for network devices.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, according the manpage `clevis-luks-unlockers(7)` having the option `_netdev` in `/etc/crypttab` is necessary to trigger the automatic unlocking.

> After a reboot, Clevis will attempt to unlock all _netdev devices listed in /etc/crypttab when systemd prompts for their
> passwords.   This  implies  that  systemd  support  for  _netdev  is
> required.

Comment: What should be the content of `crypttab` for early boot unlock? I can't find in any howto. Driing me crazy already. Only a mention of `clevis-luks-askpass.path` in arch wiki but no specific. Am I the only person with that issue???

Comment: Perhaps you should create a specific question with more details, because I don't understand totally the question (comments are not good for that) linking to this question, and someone (perhaps me if I can recall this) could help you.

Comment: Ok, I figured out. `crypttab` can stay unaware of clevis, tpm and tang. e.g. `discard` is enough of an option if one wants it. DO NOT SET `_netdev` in it of in `fstab` as advised elsewhere. Only add `rd.neednet=1` and clevis will unlock in the background if it can.